# Network Interaction Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I found this problem rather interesting, but I am not able to proceed.

> Suppose a secondary school has $n$ classes with student number $a(1), a(2), \dots, a(n)$. One day, the school arranges for a picnic to increase the interaction among students. They have $m$ spots and they'd like to group students so that no more than $k$ students of the same class are seated at the same spot. For example, if $k=1$, there is at most one member form the same class at the spot. Is it possible to obtain a group arrangement that satisfies this requirement?

Kindly suggest me some way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if $$k \ge \frac1m max \{ a(i) \}$$

That is, you find the class with the most students (call the number of students N) and they must be distributed at m spots, giving at least $\frac{N}{m}$ students per spot. If k is less than this number it cannot be done.